# Flexible List Cleaner

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
sol = ["U", "U'","U","R","R'", "R", "R", "R", "R","U","U'"]
```

I also created a function to clean this list:

```
def cleanSol(sol):
    res = '-'.join(sol)
    moveList = ['U', "U'", 'U2', 'D', "D'", 'D2', 'R', "R'", 'R2', 'L', "L'", 'L2', 'F', "F'", 'F2', 'B', "B'", 'B2', 'Y', "Y'", 'X', "X'", 'Z', "Z'", 'M', "M'", 'M2', 'E', "E'", 'E2', 'S', "S'", 'S2']
    for move in moveList:
        if move in res: # save time
            if (literal:= (f"{move}-"*4)[:-1]) and literal in res:
                res = res.replace(literal,"")
            if (literal:= f"{move}-{move}'") and literal in res:
                res = res.replace(literal,"")
            if (literal:= f"{move}'-{move}") and literal in res: 
                res = res.replace(literal,"")
            if (literal:= f"{move}-{move}") and literal in res:
                res = res.replace(literal,move+"2")
    return [r for r in res.split('-') if r] # remove emptry strings
```

**My basic requirements are:**

- If 4 continuous instances of same `move` is in `sol`, remove them. For example, if `R, R, R, R` is in `sol` remove all the instances.
- If `move` and it's inverse is in `sol`, remove them. For example, if `U, U'` is in `sol` remove all the instances.
- Same as above, just `U' U` inverse.
- If only 2 `moves` are same, add a `2`.

**Samples:-**

**Input:**

```
sol = ["U", "U'","U","R","R'", "R", "R", "R", "R","U'","U"]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> ['U']
```

**Expected Output:**

```
>>> ['U']
```

**Tweek:** I am using `-` as a simple separator and is not related with the list.

My solution works pretty well, but I think it's too length and I'm looking for efficient solutions :)

Comment: Your third case is missing an assignment (and your example input doesn't test that case).

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. Didn't give it a look. Updated :)

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: I think you can do all this using regular expressions with capture groups and back-references. E.g. `(\b\w+\b)(-\1){3}` will match 4 repetitions of a move, you can remove it using `re.sub()`.

Comment: Do you also have some other test cases?

Comment: If your list becomes `["U2", "U"]` and the next item is `"U"`, do you want to delete these 4 items ?

Comment: Yes. Basically, any `four` items that are in the list with the same value shall be removed.

Comment: @S.B. You can create any test cases, from the given moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine is also lengthy but easy to follow, I just wanted to share as a second approach.

Here I check the list in a `while True` many times, every time from the beginning. If first items are removable, I remove them and start the loop again, if not I check next few items. I've put comment for each section.

```py
def cleanSol(lst):
    while True:
        flag = False
        for i, item in enumerate(lst):
            inverse = item.replace("'", "") if "'" in item else item[0] + "'" + item[1:]

            # To remove "U" and "U'"
            if i < len(lst) - 1 and lst[i + 1] == inverse:
                del lst[i : i + 2]
                flag = True
                break

            # To remove "U", "U", "U", "U"
            if len(lst) >= 4 and set(lst[i : i + 4]) == {item}:
                del lst[i : i + 4]
                flag = True
                break

            # The two "U2", "U2", makes "U22" this should Also be removed.
            if "22" in item:
                del lst[i]
                flag = True
                break

            # To remove "U", "U2", "U"
            if i < len(lst) - 2 and item == lst[i + 2] and item == f"{lst[i+1]}2":
                del lst[i : i + 3]
                flag = True
                break

            # To convert "U", "U" to "U2"
            if i < len(lst) - 1 and item == lst[i + 1]:
                lst[i] = f"{item}2"
                del lst[i + 1]
                flag = True
                break

        if not flag:
            break
    return lst


for test in (
    ["U", "U'", "U", "R", "R'", "R", "R", "R", "R", "U'", "U"],
    ["U2", "U", "U", "R2", "R'", "R", "R"],
    ["U2", "U", "R", "R'", "U", "R", "R"],
):
    print(cleanSol(test))
```

This is now more flexible compared to the previous answer. For example it can now handle `["U2", "U", "U"]` and `["U2", "U2"]`.

Comment: If you have other test cases that will fail with this, let me know.

Comment: Great, would this also work with `["U2", "U", "U", "R2", "R'", "R2", "R"]` where I expect the output as: `[]` since `U2, U, U` becomes `U, U, U, U` so it gets eliminated and `R2, R', R2, R` when converted into `1`s (for understanding) becomes `2 - 1 + 2 + 1` which is `4` so it should also be eliminated.

Comment: Anyways, this is a better approach since some of my test cases failed with my code such as "R'-R2" returned "2". Thanks for a cool approach :) It would also be great if it could somehow return `[]` for `["U2", "U", "U", "R2", "R'", "R2", "R"]`.

Comment: @TheMyth I've re-wrote the answer with another solution. This is now more flexible than the previous one. It handles `["U2", "U", "U"]` and `["U2", "U2"]` as well.

Comment: Also, for your last if condition related to `U U U2` won't it also make `U22` since `U U` returns `U2 U2` which then makes it `U22` just like another condition used above?

Comment: @TheMyth It returns `["R"]` for `["U", "U", "U2", "R"]`. yes these create `"U22"` and there is a condition to remove that.